# Source Control Dynamics

Tags: dynamic-sql, microsoft-dynamics

What ways are there to do version control of an MS Dynamics database? I've found mentions of DACBAC, and obviously SSIS packages could just be dumped in a git repo.

I'm particularly keen on learning how to keep connections between different environments (no one wants to copy an SSIS over and have to go through each connection updating it).

Additionally, and this may be a "novice" question, but my understanding is that dacbac doesn't contain SSIS. Is this correct? Would both need to be in source control?

What is the best way!?